# can anyone suggest how to make this code short for better performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, onclick

can anyone suggest how to make this code short for better performance?
am using the following code but I think its way large to perform a small task so please suggest me a better way to write this code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tab_counter_0").click(function() {
    jQuery(".all_colors").removeClass("msk_custom_colors_1 msk_custom_colors_2 msk_custom_colors_3 msk_custom_colors_4");
  });
  jQuery(".tab_counter_1").click(function() {
    jQuery(".all_colors").removeClass("msk_custom_colors_2 msk_custom_colors_3 msk_custom_colors_4");
    jQuery(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_1 ");
  });
  jQuery(".tab_counter_2").click(function() {
    jQuery(".all_colors").removeClass("msk_custom_colors_1 msk_custom_colors_3 msk_custom_colors_4 ");
    jQuery(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_2");
  });
  jQuery(".tab_counter_3").click(function() {
    jQuery(".all_colors").removeClass("msk_custom_colors_2 msk_custom_colors_1 msk_custom_colors_4");
    jQuery(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_3");
  });
  jQuery(".tab_counter_4").click(function() {
    jQuery(".all_colors").removeClass("msk_custom_colors_3 msk_custom_colors_2 msk_custom_colors_1");
    jQuery(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_4");
  });
});
```

Comment: i think is well if you post this question on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Seems like your code is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your event handlers into a single event, use `this` and data driven code to apply the classes

```
$(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_" + $(this).data("colour"))
```

The .removeClass could be further improved by changing to reset the class, then you can add new `custom_colors_<n>` without needing to change your js.

One method might be:

```
$(".all_colors")[0].classList = $(".all_colors").data("default");
```

with `data-default=` the default class list.

Alternatively you could just clear the `classList` and set it in the code.   Depends on whether `.all_colors` is a single element, in which case use an `id=`.

As you can see there's various different ways to do this, here's one:

```js
$(".tab_counter")
  .css("cursor", "pointer")
  .click(function() {
    $(".all_colors")[0].classList = $(".all_colors").data("default");
    $(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_" + $(this).data("colour"))
  });
```

```css
.msk_custom_colors_0 { /* none */ }
.msk_custom_colors_1 { color: red }
.msk_custom_colors_2 { color: green }
.msk_custom_colors_3 { color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab_counter'>clear</div>
<div class='tab_counter' data-colour="1">1</div>
<div class='tab_counter' data-colour="2">2</div>
<div class='tab_counter' data-colour="3">3</div>
<div class='all_colors msk_custom_colors_3' data-default='all_colors'>result</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, just for fun! :)

```js
var all_numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

jQuery("[class*=tab_counter_]").click(function() {
  // class attribute of element as string
  var classes = jQuery(this).attr('class');

  // regex to find clicked number
  var clicked_number = classes.match(/(?<=tab_counter_)[\d]{1}/i)[0]; 

  // array of all numbers except clicked one
  var filtered_numbers = all_numbers.filter(x => x != clicked_number) 

  // create a list of classes to exclude
  var classes_to_remove = Array.from(filtered_numbers, (x) => `msk_custom_colors_${x}`).join(' ')

  jQuery(".all_colors").removeClass(classes_to_remove);
  jQuery(".all_colors").addClass("msk_custom_colors_"+clicked_number);
});
```

```css
.msk_custom_colors_0 { /* None */ }
.msk_custom_colors_1 { background-color: blue; }
.msk_custom_colors_2 { background-color: red; }
.msk_custom_colors_3 { background-color: green; }
.msk_custom_colors_4 { background-color: fuchsia; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <button class="tab_counter_0">0</button>
  <button class="tab_counter_1">1</button>
  <button class="tab_counter_2">2</button>
  <button class="tab_counter_3">3</button>
  <button class="tab_counter_4">4</button>
</p>

<p class="all_colors">All Colors</p>
```